# Values not inserting in database (Issue might be with foreign key)

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have added a foreign key in a table. Now, when I try to insert data from my form into the database, it doesn't work. I think the issue might be with the foreign key called 'register_id'. How can this issue be solved?

My code:

```
    <?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("cannot connect to database");
$selected = mysql_select_db("audit", $dbhandle);
$strQuery = 'SELECT * FROM schedule';
$retval = mysql_query($strQuery, $dbhandle);
if (!$retval) {
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

//insert code

if (isset($_POST['schedule'])) {
    //$id = ($_POST['id']);
    $_SESSION['company_session'] = $_POST['company_name'];
    $_SESSION['auditor_session'] = $_POST['auditor_name'];
    $_SESSION['date_session'] = $_POST['audit_date'];
    $_SESSION['time_session'] = $_POST['audit_time'];
    $_SESSION['status_session'] = $_POST['audit_status'];

    $company_session = $_SESSION['company_session'];
    $auditor_session = $_SESSION['auditor_session'];
    $date_session = $_POST['audit_date'];
    $time_session = $_POST['audit_time'];
    $status_session = $_SESSION['status_session'];

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule (company_name,auditor_name,audit_date,audit_time,audit_status) VALUES ('$company_session','$auditor_session','$date_session','$time_session','$status_session')");
    //echo ("New Process Created successfully");
    header('Location: ?');
}
?>
```

//html code

```
  <div class="form-group"><br>
                                        <table class="table">

                                            <tr><input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="id"></tr>
                                            <tr><input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="register_id"></tr>
                                            <?php
                                            $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect to the database");
                                            mysql_select_db("audit") or die("could not find db");


                                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT fullname FROM register WHERE register_id ='" . $_SESSION['register_id'] . "'");
                                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

                                            if ($numrows != 0) {
                                                $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                                                $name = $row['fullname'];
                                            }
                                            ?>

                                            <tr>   

                                                <td><label>Company Name:</label></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="company_name" required="true"></td>
                                                <td><label>Assigned Auditor:</label></td>
                                                <?php echo "<td><input class='form-control' name='auditor_name' value='$name' required='true'/></td>" ?>   

                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>                                                   
                                                <td><label>Scheduled Date:</label></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control" type="date" name="audit_date" min="2000-01-02" required="true"></td>
                                                <td><label>Scheduled Time:</label></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control" type="time" name="audit_time" required="true"></td> 
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>                                                                                                              
                                                <td><label>Status:</label></td>
                                                <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="audit_status" value="Not started" required="true"></td> 
                                                <td></td>
                                                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="schedule" value="submit">Schedule</button> &nbsp; <input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Update' name='update' /> &nbsp; <input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Delete' name='delete' /> &nbsp; <input class="btn btn-primary" type='submit' value='Reset' name='reset' /></td>
                                            </tr>

                                            </div>

                                        </table>

                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

Comment: Is there an error message anywhere? Have you checked your server's `error.log`?

Comment: You should ON error_reporting in development mode. Also mysql_* functions are deprecated and also removed in PHP 7. Use PDO or mysqli_* syntax.

Comment: You mention that `register_id` is a foreign key, but you don't have it in your `INSERT` query. Do you have a default value?

Comment: even if it is a foreign key, i need to insert it? 
no, there's no error messages displaying

Comment: Add the following to the beginning of your PHP code: `ini_set('display_errors', '1'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: yes, you need to specify the foreign key. How is it supposed to know what key/value you want? So either include it, or set a default value. If it is a primary key (auto_increment), then you can omit it.